# How to integrate a youtube channel to an android app without leaving it

Tags: android, youtube

I'm trying to integrate a youtube channel to my android application and i used this code :

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlStr ));
startActivity(intent);
```

It works fine but it opens on the youtube website so no way to come back to the app.

What can i do to make the youtube a part of the application without leaving it ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). You have all the documentation needed described there. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this

```
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytpl://"+YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_ID), this, OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
```

startActivity(lVideoIntent);

Look this project: https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/

Comment: i tried to use this library as well but everytime i run it i got an error sayin that this class is unavailable :s

Comment: You have to add this uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" and  android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: on the phone. My phone is a nexus 4

Comment: as i saw on the internet this youtube player uses a direct link to a video, and i need it to access to a channel,is that possible?